# How to populate folder browser in a Win32 Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, browser, directory

I have this win32 application that is going to be a converter for some files. What I want is a simple folder browser where you can choose files for input and destination for the converted files. I can import through drag and drop, which strangely was simpler than to do this. I tried to use `BROWSEINFO` with `SHBrowseForFolder` but using `#include <shlobj.h>` for it gives me a lot of errors. Is there any other way to get a file path through folder browsing? It is in a dialog window, using windows 8 and VS 2013

Errors: When using `#include <shobjidl.h>` for `IFileDialog` I get syntax errors in that header file. No identifier for `LPTBBUTTONSB`, `HIMAGELIST`.

Comment: Please specify what Windows versions your application will be supporting. Some solutions work only on Vista and newer versions.

Comment: sorry, it is updated now. Windows 8

Comment: The obvious solution is to solve the errors you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `#include <shobjidl.h>` before all other includes instead of last solved my compiling errors and using `IFileDialog`worked!

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not need to support XP, you can use `IFileDialog` interface. For detailed example, see this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx

The link above contains a complete implementation of function named `BasicFileOpen`, which is exactly what you need.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"Provide context for links: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*

Comment: is this the right include for it? "#include <shobjidl.h> " it still gives me the same errors as with "shlobj.h"

Comment: @Rasmus: Noone knows, what *"it"* is, that is giving you errors, or what the *"same errors"* are, that you never told us about.

Comment: Reading just this answer, how much value does it hold, *"in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline"*? The MSDN has seen numerous reorganizations in the past, and links often wound up pointing to *"Content not found"* error pages.